# Expression similar to 'as always' in this context?

Tags: phrase-request

For these expressions

> **As always** I am feeling nervous before my speech.
>
> **As always** X player scored more than half of his team's points but still lost.

Can anyone suggest to me any phrase which I can use instead of **As always** in this context.

Comment: I think "suggest *to* me" is more usual in US English.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Surely "Can anyone suggest a phrase which I can use" is more idiomatic in US and UK English than "Can anyone suggest to me any phrase which I can use..."

Comment: @Matt -- I agree that leaving out the "me" part is more idiomatic, and probably should have thought of that.  It's just that "suggest me" was so jarring that it put other possibilities out of my mind.  (Verbs with two objects and no prepositions were the subject of my master's thesis in linguistics.  "Suggest" wasn't even suggested for inclusion in that list at the time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of different phrases you might want to choose.

> **As always**, my flight was delayed.
>
> **As per usual**, my flight was delayed.
>
> My flight was delayed. **Typical**. (idiomatic, passive aggressive)
>
> **Just typical**. My flight was delayed. (idiomatic, passive aggressive)
>
> **As ever**, my flight was delayed.
>
> **Once again**, my flight was delayed.

FumbleFingers also suggested the following great alternatives:

> **Unsurprisingly**, my flight was delayed.
>
> **True to form**, my flight was delayed.

Most of these are very similar, but be careful - some are more passive aggressive than others.

Answer (score 3):

You could use *as usual* or, in the first example, *as it usually happens to me*.
In the second example, you could use *as it usually happens*, which can also be used for the other sentence.

Comment: shouldn't it be "happens TO me"?

Comment: Carlo's right that you're missing "to" there. Another alternative that's also more common than *as always* is *as **ever***. You wouldn't usually follow that with anything like "happens".

Comment: @Carlo_R. Yes, you are right. This is what happens when I am writing two answers in two different sites. `:|`

Answer (score 1):

> I am feeling nervous before my speech, **as I always do**.
>
> **As is inevitable**, I am feeling nervous before my speech.
>
> **As ever**, I am feeling nervous before my speech.
>
> **As standard**,  I am feeling nervous before my speech.

There are probably a lot more, but all of the most natural ones have been covered already.